# Tp-Link WN821N (2357:0107) not working with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb, realtek-wireless

Wireless USB - TPLINK WN821N, version - 5.
Ubuntu - version 16.04

```
sourish@sourish-ubuntu:~$ uname -a
Linux sourish-ubuntu 4.4.0-34-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 27 16:06:39    UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Used the following commands to install driver -

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms linux-firmware
```

However, after install the lsusb command does not detect the usb wifi dongle -

```
sourish@sourish-ubuntu:~$ lsusb 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2357:0107  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 04d9:1702 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. Keyboard LKS02
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Please provide a solution. Am I missing some steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dongle is detected. It is

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2357:0107
```

You installed a wrong driver for it. You can install it by

```
sudo apt-get purge rtlwifi-new-dkms
sudo apt-get install rtl8192eu-dkms
```

from the same PPA.

I patched the official driver provided by Tp-link to be used with the 4.4 kernel.

In your case you already installed the PPA, but for other people who use this device, they need to run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtl8192eu-dkms
```

to install the driver.

To install the driver you need to be connected to internet by other means and Secure Boot in UEFI settings should be disabled.

Comment: followed the mentioned steps. The tp-link usb wifi dongle is working fine now. Thanks!

Comment: and for kernel 4.8 do you have also a patch somewhere ? :/

Comment: @ZheFrench No, I don't. It can be done, but I am still using the 4.4.