# Tp-Link WN821N (2357:0107) not working

Tags: networking, drivers, tp-link

I followed the instructions on that post, but my dongle seems not to work: [Tp-Link WN821N (2357:0107) not working with Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/817847/tp-link-wn821n-23570107-not-working-with-ubuntu-16-04/879830?noredirect=1)

After installing the RTL8192EU driver, it finally detects the dongle and shows some information when typing `iwconfig` in the console (see below). but even then, the dongle is not showing anywhere else and I can not search for wireless networks.

```
anthonidas@AnthoUnixSurface:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2357:0107  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0003 VMware, Inc. Virtual Mouse
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
anthonidas@AnthoUnixSurface:~$ iwconfig
ens33     no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

enx98ded013b4aa  unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

anthonidas@AnthoUnixSurface:~$ uname -a
Linux AnthoUnixSurface 4.4.0-62-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 18 14:10:15 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Does anyone have an idea what I did wrong? Is the TP-Link WN821N not compatible with Linux?

**Edit**
this is the output of dkms status:

```
anthonidas@AnthoUnixSurface:~$ dkms status
rtl8192eu, 4.4, 4.4.0-62-generic, x86_64: installed
```

**EDIT2**
here we go:

```
anthonidas@AnthoUnixSurface:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Comment: The driver is installed. Please add the output of `cat /etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: I have to say, that I am new to linux... so thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: All looks OK. I have no more ideas.

Comment: In the top bar it shows only an ethernet wired connection.  As written in the main post, `iwconfig` shows 'unassociated'. Do I perhaps have to associate anything manually?

Comment: Did you disable Secure Boot in BIOS? And it looks like you created a hot spot.

Comment: I am on VMWare, i have modified the *.vmx file adding this line `firmware = "efi"` but Secure Boot does not appear in the BIOS. Is VMWare's default not already "off" and you have to turn it on manually in case you want a secure boot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I finally found the solution in the Kali-Linux Forum and it works for Ubuntu too.

What I did first was to uninstall your driver and download that one: https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver, but in fact I did not check if it is the same... so I am pretty sure that it would have worked with your driver aswell.

Anyway **the final solution was to blacklist the CU-Driver**!!

So for everyone having the same issue, do the following:

```
1. Download the rtl8192eu driver from the above link or from pilot's repo
2. Install it with make and sudo make install
3. Blacklist the rtl8192cu driver
   in terminal type: sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
   add a new line with that --> blacklist rtl8192cu
   save the file
4. Reboot and AFTERWARDS plug your dongle in
5. The post in kali-linux's forum said, that for that guy it hadn't worked on the first try. In that case he suggested just to repeat the installation several times.
```

I don't take any credits, I just copied NL2016's answer here because it was helpful for me and it could be for others too... If you want to read his discussion, here it is: https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?34548-TP-Link-TL-WN821N-Wifi-Adaptor-no-interface&p=67560&viewfull=1#post67560

Comment: It is weird that rtl8192cu is involved. Probably someone added a wrong ID to the kernel driver.

Comment: I looked into the sources and this is not the case. You probably previously installed a wrong driver.

Comment: I really don't know how it is possible, but the first driver i installed was the one i linked in the question. Afterwards I tried some other drivers (wrong drivers aswell) but every time it didn't work i uninstalled them.

Comment: This is a mystery.

Comment: Well, I am happy that finally it works and thank you for your help. Relly appreciate it. :)