# TP-Link WN-822N (rtl8192eu) not working

Tags: networking, drivers, uefi, realtek-wireless

I have tried some of the hints posted here such as [Tp-Link WN821N (2357:0107) not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879868/tp-link-wn821n-23570107-not-working) but I can't get my dongle to even blink its led.

Follow here an excerpt of dmesg output. As a side note, I have disabled UEFI secure mode boot as this module is not signed. It seems to work, despite the warning at the first line, but it never lights up its led or anything. It register an interface, renames it from wlan0 to enx18d6c71c8c30 (basically its MAC address) and I can see it up in ifconfig (with no IP address associated to it, though).

Also, I can see in the network manager the little airplane and the wifi icons if I put the wireless interface down, modprobe -r, modprobe again and ifconfig up. But I hava advanced no more than that. Can somebody help?

```
[    3.033949] 8192eu: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    3.035185] RTL871X: module init start
[    3.035187] RTL871X: rtl8192eu v4.3.1.1_11320.20140505
[    3.035188] RTL871X: build time: Sep 17 2017 12:01:28
[    3.035206] RTL871X: 
               usb_endpoint_descriptor(0):
[    3.035207] RTL871X: bLength=7
[    3.035207] RTL871X: bDescriptorType=5
[    3.035208] RTL871X: bEndpointAddress=84
[    3.035209] RTL871X: wMaxPacketSize=512
[    3.035209] RTL871X: bInterval=0
[    3.035210] RTL871X: RT_usb_endpoint_is_bulk_in = 4
[    3.035210] RTL871X: 
               usb_endpoint_descriptor(1):
[    3.035211] RTL871X: bLength=7
[    3.035211] RTL871X: bDescriptorType=5
[    3.035212] RTL871X: bEndpointAddress=5
[    3.035212] RTL871X: wMaxPacketSize=512
[    3.035213] RTL871X: bInterval=0
[    3.035213] RTL871X: RT_usb_endpoint_is_bulk_out = 5
[    3.035214] RTL871X: 
               usb_endpoint_descriptor(2):
[    3.035215] RTL871X: bLength=7
[    3.035215] RTL871X: bDescriptorType=5
[    3.035216] RTL871X: bEndpointAddress=6
[    3.035216] RTL871X: wMaxPacketSize=512
[    3.035216] RTL871X: bInterval=0
[    3.035217] RTL871X: RT_usb_endpoint_is_bulk_out = 6
[    3.035217] RTL871X: 
               usb_endpoint_descriptor(3):
[    3.035218] RTL871X: bLength=7
[    3.035219] RTL871X: bDescriptorType=5
[    3.035219] RTL871X: bEndpointAddress=87
[    3.035220] RTL871X: wMaxPacketSize=64
[    3.035220] RTL871X: bInterval=3
[    3.035221] RTL871X: RT_usb_endpoint_is_int_in = 7, Interval = 3
[    3.035221] RTL871X: 
               usb_endpoint_descriptor(4):
[    3.035222] RTL871X: bLength=7
[    3.035222] RTL871X: bDescriptorType=5
[    3.035223] RTL871X: bEndpointAddress=8
[    3.035223] RTL871X: wMaxPacketSize=512
[    3.035224] RTL871X: bInterval=0
[    3.035224] RTL871X: RT_usb_endpoint_is_bulk_out = 8
[    3.035225] RTL871X: nr_endpoint=5, in_num=2, out_num=3

[    3.035226] RTL871X: USB_SPEED_HIGH
[    3.035229] RTL871X: CHIP TYPE: RTL8192E
[    3.035233] RTL871X: register rtw_netdev_ops to netdev_ops
[    3.035260] RTL871X: ReadChipVersion192e 0xF0 = 0xc441137 
[    3.035261] RTL871X: Chip Version Info: CHIP_8192E_Normal_Chip_SMIC_B_CUT_2T2R_RomVer(0)
[    3.035262] RTL871X: RF_Type is 2!!
[    3.035262] RTL871X: _ConfigChipOutEP_8192E OutEpQueueSel(0x07), OutEpNumber(3) 
[    3.035263] RTL871X: ====> ReadAdapterInfo8192EU
[    3.035307] RTL871X: Boot from EFUSE, Autoload OK !
[    3.087168] RTL871X: EEPROM ID=0x8129
[    3.087170] RTL871X: VID = 0x2357, PID = 0x0108
[    3.087171] RTL871X: Customer ID: 0x00, SubCustomer ID: 0xCD
[    3.087172] RTL871X: hal_ReadMACAddress_8192EU MAC Address from EFUSE = 18:d6:c7:1c:8c:30
[    3.087173] RTL871X: Hal_ReadPowerSavingMode8192E...bHWPwrPindetect(0)-bHWPowerdown(0) ,bSupportRemoteWakeup(1)
[    3.087174] RTL871X: ### PS params=>  power_mgnt(1),usbss_enable(0) ###
[    3.087175] RTL871X: EEPROMRegulatory = 0x1 TxPwrCalibrateRate=0x0
[    3.087176] RTL871X: Board Type: Dongle or WIFI only Module 
[    3.087177] RTL871X: mlmepriv.ChannelPlan = 0x21
[    3.087194] RTL871X: CrystalCap: 0x3e
[    3.087194] RTL871X: ThermalMeter = 0x1b
[    3.087195] RTL871X: SWAS: bHwAntDiv = 0, TRxAntDivType = ff
[    3.087195] RTL871X: pHalData->PAType_2G is 0x0, pHalData->ExternalPA_2G = 0
[    3.087196] RTL871X: pHalData->LNAType_2G is 0x0, pHalData->ExternalLNA_2G = 0
[    3.087197] RTL871X: ReadAdapterInfo8192EU <====
[    3.087263] RTL871X: init_channel_set ChannelPlan ID 21 Chan num:13  
[    3.087345] RTL871X: pwrctrlpriv.bSupportRemoteWakeup~~~~~~
[    3.087346] RTL871X: pwrctrlpriv.bSupportRemoteWakeup~~~[1]~~~
[    3.087347] RTL871X: can't get autopm: 
[    3.087348] RTL871X: rtw_macaddr_cfg MAC Address  = 18:d6:c7:1c:8c:30
[    3.087349] RTL871X: bDriverStopped:1, bSurpriseRemoved:0, bup:0, hw_init_completed:0
[    3.087353] RTL871X: rtw_ndev_init(wlan0)
[    3.087911] RTL871X: _rtw_drv_register_netdev, MAC Address (if1) = 18:d6:c7:1c:8c:30
[    3.087933] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8192eu
[    3.087951] RTL871X: module init ret=0
[    3.089123] rtl8192eu 1-4:1.0 enx18d6c71c8c30: renamed from wlan0
[    3.121297] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[    3.121299] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[    3.121300] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[    3.121301] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    3.121302] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    3.121303] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    3.121304] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    3.121305] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[    3.121306] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[    3.121307] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    3.121307] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[    3.159121] RTL871X: +871x_drv - drv_open, bup=0
[    3.159125] RTL871X: ==>_InitPowerOn_8192EU 
[    3.160360] RTL871X: SetHwReg8192E: bMacPwrCtrlOn=1
[    3.160560] RTL871X:  ===> FirmwareDownload88E() fw source from Header.
[    3.160561] RTL871X: FirmwareDownload8192E fw:NIC, size: 31818
[    3.160562] RTL871X: FirmwareDownload8192E: fw_ver=19 fw_subver=0 sig=0x92e1
[    3.160919] RTL871X: =====> _8051Reset8192E(): 8051 reset success .
[    3.180939] RTL871X: polling_fwdl_chksum: Checksum report OK! (1, 0ms), REG_MCUFWDL:0x00070605
[    3.181377] RTL871X: =====> _8051Reset8192E(): 8051 reset success .
[    3.205904] RTL871X: _FWFreeToGo8192E: Polling FW ready OK! (578, 24ms), REG_MCUFWDL:0x000706c6
[    3.205906] RTL871X: FWDL success. write_fw:1, 44ms
[    3.210076] RTL871X: ===> phy_BB8192E_Config_ParaFile() EEPROMRegulatory 1
[    3.225220] RTL871X: PHY_BBConfig8192E ==> CrystalCap:0x3e 
[    3.761147] RTL871X: Auto InitLLTTable8192E success 
[    3.771469] RTL871X: pDM_Odm TxPowerTrackControl = 1
[    3.928107] RTL871X: phy_SpurCalibration_8192E =>AFE_PHASE_SEL 
[    3.988765] RTL871X: === PathA=1, PathB=1
[    3.988767] RTL871X: ===FixSpur Pass!
[    3.996901] RTL871X: enx18d6c71c8c30 MAC Address from REG_MACID = 18:d6:c7:1c:8c:30
[    3.996903] RTL871X: rtl8192eu_hal_init in 840ms
[    3.996905] RTL871X: enx18d6c71c8c30Port-0  set opmode = 2
[    4.003039] RTL871X: MAC Address = 18:d6:c7:1c:8c:30
[    4.003161] RTL871X: -871x_drv - drv_open, bup=1
[    4.003182] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enx18d6c71c8c30: link is not ready
[    6.006180] RTL871X: ==>rtw_ps_processor .fw_state(8)
[    6.006182] RTL871X: ==>ips_enter cnts:1
[    6.006182] RTL871X: nolinked power save enter
[    6.006183] RTL871X: ===> rtw_ips_pwr_down...................
[    6.006184] RTL871X: ====> rtw_ips_dev_unload...
[    6.020408] RTL871X: usb_read_port_cancel
[    6.020457] RTL871X: usb_read_port_complete() RX Warning! bDriverStopped(0) OR bSurpriseRemoved(0) 
[    6.020496] RTL871X: usb_read_port_complete() RX Warning! bDriverStopped(0) OR bSurpriseRemoved(0) 
[    6.020536] RTL871X: usb_read_port_complete() RX Warning! bDriverStopped(0) OR bSurpriseRemoved(0) 
[    6.020575] RTL871X: usb_read_port_complete() RX Warning! bDriverStopped(0) OR bSurpriseRemoved(0) 
[    6.020616] RTL871X: usb_read_port_complete() RX Warning! bDriverStopped(0) OR bSurpriseRemoved(0) 
[    6.020655] RTL871X: usb_read_port_complete() RX Warning! bDriverStopped(0) OR bSurpriseRemoved(0) 
[    6.020696] RTL871X: usb_read_port_complete() RX Warning! bDriverStopped(0) OR bSurpriseRemoved(0) 
[    6.020735] RTL871X: usb_read_port_complete() RX Warning! bDriverStopped(0) OR bSurpriseRemoved(0) 
[    6.020738] RTL871X: usb_write_port_cancel 
[    6.020745] RTL871X: ==> rtl8192eu_hal_deinit 
[    6.020977] RTL871X: bkeepfwalive(0)
[    6.020978] RTL871X:  hal_poweroff_8192eu
[    6.022378] RTL871X: SetHwReg8192E: bMacPwrCtrlOn=0
[    6.022378] RTL871X: <=== rtw_ips_pwr_down..................... in 16ms
```

Comment: Please make your question, meaningful.

Comment: OK, sorry... I believe I was a bit anxious posting for the first time. I have this TP-Link wireless usb adapter that I can't get to work, and I am not sure of what is wrong exactly, but despite showing the interface as up in ifconfig, there is no IP address associated to it and I have no network in this machine. The question should be "what is wrong here?" or "How do I get this adapter to work properly?"

Comment: It sounds like you've got airplane mode enabled, and no wireless network interface will work then. Either disable airplane mode, and/or turn on the hardware wireless enable switch located on the side of your computer, and/or hit the appropriate function key for your computer to enable the wireless. What driver did you install for this?

Comment: I have the rtl8192eu driver as this is an WN822N with firmware v4.0. Now I could make the dongle blink with `iwconfig enx18d6c71c8c30 channel 11 essid mynet key s:mypasswd [2]`but still I can't seem to get an IP... dhclient returns nothing. –

Comment: May be the network you are connecting to does not have a DHCP server running or it has one but for security reasons it's not allocating you with a DHCP address. Perhaps your MAC address needs to be white-listed. To really know whether you have a problem, you could get a cheap and conventional wireless router (Linksys, D-LINK, TP-Link) and connect to it. Normally consumer-focused WiFi routers have DHCP enabled but in case it does not, you can enable it via the web interface.

Comment: Other computers and smartphones are in the same network with no problems: `ID IP Address MAC Address Hostname Reserved Status Operation
1 192.168.1.6 34:be:00:96:60:e7 android-9376bdc5f321f914 No Online 
2 192.168.1.2 2c:ae:2b:0c:b0:51 android-22da8df5c2833af8 No Online 
...
9 192.168.1.15 40:16:7e:bc:2c:ad Banner No Online 
10 192.168.1.10 84:7b:eb:e5:76:0e DESKTOP-13N7BJ5 No Online`

Comment: Ok see if this [link](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=219909) link helps you - this is for ArchLinux but you should be able to use the suggestions with Ubuntu with no issues. The answer is in post 2 and you can try using the `wpa_supplicant` command. For a  `wpa_supplicant`, tutorial (very simple and easy) read this [link](https://linuxconfig.org/connect-to-wifi-from-the-linux-command-line).