# Ubuntu 18.04 - Tp Link dongle - fail connecting network ( model TL-WN821N )

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, network-manager, tp-link

I'm using a fresh installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a PC, which mainly uses a wired network, but a wifi connection is also needed from time to time. For that, I'm using a wifi dongle - which works OK when dual boot as Windows, but when using Ubuntu: it DOES detect networks at home- but does NOT connect any.

TP-Links site refers to driver installation, includig a well detailed instructions doing so [link to TP-LINK driver](https://www.tp-link.com/us/download/TL-WN821N.html#Driver), which fails at very beginning as shown below at ATTCH #1.

Second try: referring to an almost exact problem [posted](https://askubuntu.com/a/880455/688300) here, but again, fails again at `make`

Appreciate you kind help

Guy

ATTCH#1

```
guy@desktop:~/Downloads/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047$ make clean
#make -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-20-generic/build M=/home/guy/Downloads/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047 clean
cd hal ; rm -fr */*/*/*.mod.c */*/*/*.mod */*/*/*.o */*/*/.*.cmd */*/*/*.ko
cd hal ; rm -fr */*/*.mod.c */*/*.mod */*/*.o */*/.*.cmd */*/*.ko
cd hal ; rm -fr */*.mod.c */*.mod */*.o */.*.cmd */*.ko
cd hal ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd core/efuse ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd core ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd os_dep/linux ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd os_dep ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd platform ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
rm -fr Module.symvers ; rm -fr Module.markers ; rm -fr modules.order
rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko *~
rm -fr .tmp_versions
guy@desktop:~/Downloads/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047$ ma
ma: command not found
guy@desktop:~/Downloads/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047$ make
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-20-generic/build M=/home/guy/Downloads/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-20-generic'
Makefile:976: "Cannot use CONFIG_STACK_VALIDATION=y, please install libelf-dev, libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel"
  CC [M]  /home/guy/Downloads/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/core/rtw_cmd.o
In file included from /home/guy/Downloads/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/include/osdep_service.h:47:0,
                 from /home/guy/Downloads/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/include/drv_types.h:27,
                 from /home/guy/Downloads/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/core/rtw_cmd.c:17:
/home/guy/Downloads/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/include/osdep_service_linux.h: In function ‘_init_timer’:
/home/guy/Downloads/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/include/osdep_service_linux.h:299:8: error: ‘_timer {aka struct timer_list}’ has no member named ‘data’
  ptimer->data = (unsigned long)cntx;
        ^~
/home/guy/Downloads/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/include/osdep_service_linux.h:300:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘init_timer’; did you mean ‘_init_timer’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  init_timer(ptimer);
  ^~~~~~~~~~
  _init_timer
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:332: recipe for target '/home/guy/Downloads/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/core/rtw_cmd.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/guy/Downloads/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
Makefile:1552: recipe for target '_module_/home/guy/Downloads/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/guy/Downloads/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-20-generic'
Makefile:1828: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

In latest kernel some function obsolete so original driver need to modify according to new kernel.
download tp link drive from following link.

https://github.com/ZeeRooo/RTL8192EU

goto driver folder and run follwing commands.

```
# apt update
# apt-get install gcc make libelf-dev
# make
# make install
```

remove wifi usb dongle and reboot system.
Install wifi module

```
# modprobe 8192eu
```

now insert wifi dongle and test.
working for me tested on ubuntu 18.04 and Arch linux.